# Storing all nonzero elements of a 2-D array via slicing

Tags: julia

for extracting all nonzero elemnts of an one dimentional array, we do the following:

```
One_D = [1,4,5,0,0,4,7,0,2,6]
One_D[One_D .> 0]
```

How to do a similar thing for a two or more than 2 dimentinal vectore array?

```
two_D = [[1,0,2,3,0],[4,0,5,0,6]]
```

this `two_D[two_D .> 0]` obviously is incorrect. So, what esle we can try?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `two_D` is not 2 dimensional, but it is a vector of vectors. You can use then broadcasted `filter`:

```
julia> filter.(>(0), two_D)
2-element Vector{Vector{Int64}}:
 [1, 2, 3]
 [4, 5, 6]
```

If instead your `two_D` were a matrix like this:

```
julia> mat = [[1,0,2,3,0] [4,0,5,0,6]]
5×2 Matrix{Int64}:
 1  4
 0  0
 2  5
 3  0
 0  6
```

You can still use `filter` but without broadcasting. In this case you will get a flat vector of found elements:

```
julia> filter(>(0), mat)
6-element Vector{Int64}:
 1
 2
 3
 4
 5
 6
```